# generate a current,30,60,90 day aging report with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get aging of invoices report from a mysql table. The table has a client_id, an amount_due, and a due_date for each invoice.  I am grabbing all the invoices from each client, one client at a time.

I have searched SO for a solution and found several but when I try to implement them, I get the same error ...

> "unknown column '`days_past_due`"....

I have tried several snippets of mysql code and each one errors the same way, I researched the error and it seems I can't use a column alias at the same level(don't quite understand that).  I tried this first. (NOTE: INV_DDATE is stored as a unix timestamp, an 11 digit integer)

```
select INV_NUM
     , INV_DDATE
     , DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME(INV_DDATE)) days_past_due
     , INV_DBAL total_ar
     , SUM(IF(days_past_due = 0, total_ar, 0))
     , SUM(IF(days_past_due BETWEEN 1 AND 30, total_ar, 0))
     , SUM(IF(days_past_due BETWEEN 31 AND 60, total_ar, 0))
     , SUM(IF(days_past_due BETWEEN 61 AND 90, total_ar, 0))
     , SUM(IF(days_past_due > 90, total_ar, 0)) 
  from invoice_table 
 where INV_CODE = 'the_client code'
```

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'days_past_due' in 'field list'.

Comment: the answer from panther misses the actual problem ... an attempt to reference an alias assigned in the SELECT list elsewhere in the same query ... that can't be referenced in other expressions in the SELECT list, or in the WHERE clause, et al. (somewhat confusingly, the alias can be referenced later in statement processing, in a HAVING clause or ORDER BY clause)

Answer (score 0):

There can't be quotes around the alias name.

```
select INV_NUM, INV_DDATE, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME(INV_DDATE)) AS days_past_due, INV_DBAL as total_ar ...
```

If you need to use something around, it has to be backticks (`).

```
select INV_NUM, INV_DDATE, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME(INV_DDATE)) AS `days_past_due`, INV_DBAL as `total_ar` ...
```

Comment: beat me to it x3

Comment: yah , should not use single quotes around identifiers ... we can use backticks (or double quotes if sql_mode includes) ANSI_QUOTES but unfortunately MySQL does allow the non-standard use of single quotes, where other RDBMS would pitch a fit...   the crux of OP problem is attempt to reference an alias assigned in the SELECT list elsewhere in the same query, in other expressions in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse alias in SELECT block. You should replace all occurrences of `days_past_due` with `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME(INV_DDATE))` or use variables/subqueries.

Comment: i concur with panther's point  (single quotes are for string literals, if we are going to escape identifiers, we should use MySQL backtick characters, or if we are going to use sql_mode including ANSI_QUOTES, we can use double quotes. But yah, apart from that, panther's answer is a swing and a miss ... swoosh ... totally missed the actual problem. (The downvoting of correct answers is a problem on SO. My apologies from the community.)

Answer (score 0):

An alias assigned to an expression in a `SELECT` list can't be referenced elsewhere in the `SELECT` list, or in the `WHERE` clause. (It is available for referencing later in statement processing, in a `HAVING` clause or `ORDER BY` clause.)

One approach (potentially expensive) is to use an inline view, provide the alias there, and then in the outer query, the assigned alias can be referenced as a column name.

```
SELECT v.my_alias 
  FROM ( -- inline view 
         SELECT t.foo AS my_alias 
           FROM ...
       ) v
```

e.g.

```
SELECT v.INV_NUM
     , v.INV_DDATE
     , v.days_past_due
     , v.total_ar
     , SUM(IF( v.days_past_due = 0               ,v.total_ar,0))
     , SUM(IF( v.days_past_due BETWEEN  1 AND 30 ,v.total_ar,0))
     , SUM(IF( v.days_past_due BETWEEN 31 AND 60 ,v.total_ar,0))
     , SUM(IF( v.days_past_due BETWEEN 61 AND 90 ,v.total_ar,0))
     , SUM(IF( v.days_past_due > 90              ,v.total_ar,0))
  FROM (
         SELECT t.INV_NUM
              , t.INV_DDATE
              , DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME(t.INV_DDATE)) AS `days_past_due`
              , t.INV_DBAL                                      AS `total_ar`
           FROM invoice_table t
          WHERE t.INV_CODE = 'the_client code'
       ) v
```

This can be expensive because of the way MySQL processes the inline view, creating and populating an intermediate table (called a "derived table"), before the outer query runs.

---

Other than that, our option is to just repeat that same expression to derive "days_past_due", e.g.

```
SELECT t.INV_NUM
     , t.INV_DDATE
     , DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),FROM_UNIXTIME(t.INV_DDATE)) AS `days_past_due`
     , t.INV_DBAL                                     AS `total_ar`
     , SUM(IF( DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),FROM_UNIXTIME(t.INV_DDATE)) = 0               ,t.INV_DBAL,0))
     , SUM(IF( DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),FROM_UNIXTIME(t.INV_DDATE)) BETWEEN  1 AND 30 ,t.INV_DBAL,0))
     , SUM(IF( DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),FROM_UNIXTIME(t.INV_DDATE)) BETWEEN 31 AND 60 ,t.INV_DBAL,0))
     , SUM(IF( DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),FROM_UNIXTIME(t.INV_DDATE)) BETWEEN 61 AND 90 ,t.INV_DBAL,0))
     , SUM(IF( DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),FROM_UNIXTIME(t.INV_DDATE)) > 90              ,t.INV_DBAL,0))
  FROM invoice_table t
 WHERE t.INV_CODE = 'the_client code'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,
Thanks to all for the suggestions and yes, I skipped the alias and just used the expression.  Worked perfectly!
    select 
    INV_NUM,
    INV_DDATE,
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(INV_DDATE)) < 30 then INV_DBAL else 0 end) as ZeroToThirty,
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(INV_DDATE)) > 31 and DATEDIFF(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(INV_DDATE)) < 60 then INV_DBAL else 0 end) as ThirtyToSixty,
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(INV_DDATE)) > 61 and DATEDIFF(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(INV_DDATE)) < 90 then INV_DBAL  else 0 end) as SixtyToNinety,
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(curdate(), FROM_UNIXTIME(INV_DDATE)) > 120 then INV_DBAL else 0 end) as NinetyToOneTwenty
    from invoice_table
    where INV_CODE = 'the_client code';

I hope this helps someone else.